# Copy an entire row from one sheet to another based upon a single word, within a paragraph, inside a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to copy a row from one sheet to another based upon having a specific word in the cell. I have a sheet one, called "data" and a sheet two called "final".

Here is an example of the data

```
A         B            C               D  
john      mary         555.555.4939    initial reply to phone conversation  
Jim       jack         555.555.5555    floor estimate for bathroom  
jerry     kim          555.555.5553    initial response to phone call
```

I'd like to copy the entire row from sheet "data" to a sheet "final" if the data in column D contains either the word "reply" or the word "response".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
Sub Foo()

Dim i As Long, iMatches As Long
Dim aTokens() As String: aTokens = Split("reply,response", ",")

For Each cell In Sheets("data").Range("D:D")

    If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then Exit For

    For i = 0 To UBound(aTokens)
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, aTokens(i), vbTextCompare) Then
            iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
            Sheets("data").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("final").Rows(iMatches)
        End If
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Voted up for the short way to copy one row to another: WorkSheet1.Rows(Row1).Copy WorkSheet2.Rows(Row2)! Everywhere else the examples were including loops ...